# Promise rejection not getting catched

Tags: javascript

Why is a promise rejection not catched here? I tried to debug it but reason never gets executed

```
   axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
        contractId: contractValue
      }).then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
      }, (reason) => {
        console.log(reason)
      })
```

Comment: Are you sure it is rejecting? Your catch handler will only get invoked if `axios.post` rejects. Is `setLoading` or `setButton` throwing an error?

Comment: *Which* rejection is not get caught? Please provide a [mcve]. Your code looks totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead try putting a `catch` in your promise chain. It will catch any exceptions in the chain before it. It would look something like this:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
    contractId: contractValue,
})
    .then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // this is where you handle your exception
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the function as a second argument, you can add the `.catch` block that will handle all exceptions when thrown

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
  contractId: contractValue
}).then(() => {
  setLoading(false)
  setButton(null)
}).catch((reason) => {
  console.log(reason)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> onRejected never handles rejected promises from the same .then(onFulfilled) callback and .catch takes both.

```js
const getPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  Math.round(Math.random()) ?     resolve('resolve #1') :     reject('reject #1')})

getPromise().then(result => {  throw new Error('reject #2')}, error => {  // Handles only 'reject #1'})

getPromise().then(result => {  throw new Error('reject #2')})  .catch(error => {    // Handles both 'reject #1',     // and 'reject #2'  }))
```

Above description was from this link: [The real difference between catch vs onRejected](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-real-difference-between-catch-vs-onrejected-15cab8978e92/)